# Qt audioinput error : pcm_params.c :2348 : sndrv_pcm_hw_params: L'assertion « err >= 0

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qt4

I'm trying to execute the audioinput sample for the Qt SDK, but i get the following message error at the starting of the program:

```
pcm_params.c :2348 : sndrv_pcm_hw_params:  L'assertion « err >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the problem is with your pulseaudio setup. Or it can be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/549776). Try a suggestion. Try the pulseaudio package from from ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev